# redux how to redirect on componentWillMount using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

how to redirect on componentWillMount using react-router

```
export class NewStock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { session, dispatch, router } = this.props
    if (session.userSessionData.get('logged_in') == false) {
      router.transitionTo('/login')
    }
  };
```

this code:

```
router.transitionTo('/login')
```

only return:

```
Uncaught TypeError: router.transitionTo is not a function
```

Comment: I only saw examples where the transitionTo() was used from the Router.Navigation mixin. You need to add that mixin, and then you'll be able to say `this.transitionTo(...)`

Comment: One more thing, probably it's better to transition programatically on a willTransitionTo static callback. This will prevent your view being visible for a short while before your transitionTo() is called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `this.props.history`:

```
const { history } = this.props
history.pushState(null, '/login') or
history.replaceState(null, '/login')
```

If your module isn't a direct descendant of the router you can still access this prop by wrapping your component in the `withRouter(YourComponent)` HOC (in v4).

Comment: For me I get `Cannot read property 'pushState' of undefined`. Seems like I have no context on my component. (used the same definition and constructor)

Comment: I must apologize, I did not realize this was with redux. I'm doing Flux atm. So I cannot possibly work anyhow for me.

Comment: Apologies I got confused actually it's not redux specific - history is passed to the router and it should be provided in context e.g. - `<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>`

Answer (score 2):

What I'm doing is using the `onEnter` prop of a route. This allows me to centralize my authentication better. I got my inspiration from [the react-router examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow)

I came here because I was fumbling about with the same aproach as you, but got into an huge mess of unmanageable code VERY SOON.

Hope that for all coming here, you will learn from my mistake.

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!UserStore.userIsSignedIn()) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/login',
            state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
        })
    }
}

render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={PageHeader}>
            <IndexRoute component={AssignmentOverview} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
            <Route path="login" component={UserLoginForm}/>
            <Route path="logout" component={UserLogout}/>
            <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
            <Route path="assignmentform" component={AssignmentForm} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: I like having a higher order components that wraps all the pages that requires auth. The problem with your method is that it is possible to see an auth page without being authenticated. Just log out without redirecting. I like better componentDidMount + componentWillReceiveProps. If the auth changes while being on the page, I will still be redirected and I don't need to put the redirect login in every log out button.

Comment: v4 update: `onEnter` property is removed and docs suggest to use `componentWillMount` instead: [source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7c0481966e9f79da47ea483e083a4f694ecf35fe/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties)